# Struggling with friendly urls in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I edited the permalink settings by changing the custom structure to:

```
/%postname%/
```

Now, when I click on a page link it'll take me to domain.com/postname, but I get a 404 error. Doing some digging this shows that I need to setup 301 redirects, but I'm confused as to how to do this. I've edited my .htaccess file - it now looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mgassoc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mgassoc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your htaccess looks good, try switching back to default and then again to custom structure, see if it works.. Does it throw a warning saying it cant write to your htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't throw an error, and it still gives me 404s. When I go back into the settings it has switched back to the postname radio, rather than the custom one.

Comment: I've tried /%pagename%/ too, same result.

Comment: yes because `/%postname%/` is considered postname and not custom, custom structure would be if you created your own thats not listed

Comment: Ah right, could you tell me how to get the page title as url? e.g. domain.com/page-title. Is there a specific tutorial for this?

Comment: did you try switching to the default one and then selecting `page-name` again ?

Comment: Page name doesn't seem to be an option - I have: day and name, month and name, numeric, post name and custom structure.

Comment: try switching to default and then back to post name...

Comment: I've tried that, still the same. Could it be something to do with mod_rewrite? How can I check that it's functioning correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27867/discussion-between-david-chase-and-babbaggeii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this and see if it helps.

Add the following into your httpd.conf and re-start apache.

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/app"> 
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```